# Confusion about superclass references and subclass objects

Tags: java, inheritance, reference, modifier, overriding

I have some questions about this code:

```
class superclass
{
    void bark() {}
}

class subclass extends superclass
{
    void bark() {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        superclass refvar = new subclass();
        refvar.bark();
    }
}
```

1. Why is it necessary for the parent to have a method in this case, whether the child has it or not? I am told that at compile time the reference variable is of superclass type, so the compiler checks for this method in the superclass at compile time; is that accurate?
2. When the compiler reads `bark()`, how does it know where to go next? I know the child method overrides it, but I want to know that first it goes to the superclass method or subclass, and why.
3. Why does the subclass need to have an access modifier of wider scope?

Comment: This is basic Object Oriented Programming principle. Please go thorough this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

Answer (score 1):

1. `refvar` is declared as a `superclass` object, which is why `bark()` has to be declared in `superclass` for `refvar.bark()` to compile.
2. It looks for the instance object's implementation of `bark()`.
3. It doesn't make a lot of sense to override something to a narrower scope.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is it necessary for the parent to have a method in this case,
>   whether the child has it or not?

Your example is calling `bark()` on an object statically typed as `superclass` - if `superclass` didn't declare the method `bark()`, the compiler wouldn't know that this would be a valid call.

> I am told that at compile time the
>   reference variable is of superclass type, so the compiler checks for
>   this method in the superclass at compile time; is that accurate?

Yes, in fact this is along the lines of what I said above.

> When the compiler reads `bark()`, how does it know where to go next? I
>   know the child method overrides it, but I want to know that first it
>   goes to the superclass method or subclass, and why.

Actually, the compiler doesn't go anywhere next. All that matters at compile time is that `bark()` is a valid call on an object of type `superclass`. It's only at runtime that the call is dispatched to the `bark()` override declared in `subclass`.

> Why does the subclass need to have an access modifier of wider scope?

I'm assuming you mean the subclass's *overridden method* here. To clarify, it must have *equal* or wider access. The reason it can't have narrower access is because that would break the contract defined by the superclass.

For example if you were allowed to change `bark()` to be `private` in `subclass`, then a call to that method theoretically shouldn't work outside of `subclass`. But it needs to work, since `superclass` didn't make `bark()` private:

```
class ClassInTheSamePackageAsTheOtherTwo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        superclass refvar = new subclass();
        refvar.bark(); //as far as the compiler knows, this call is valid
    }
}
```